# Andengine Scene Manager and Handler

Tags: java, android, handler, andengine

I created some activities and different scenes. Now I'd like to merge them all using Scene Manager.
But I got problems with
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() as I used handlers.
Can anyone provide me with a quick solution?
Which mechanism should be used to make a Scene Manager from separated classes/activities?

Specifically: I cannot use handler inside my nested class. Sorry for the fact that this becomes to Java question, not just Andengine.

```
   public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
   {

    public static class SceneManager1 {

    public static Handler handlerAchievementOwl = new Handler(){
        @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            Log.i("Peakpeak","Peak inside Handler");
            }

    };
   }

   }
```

Comment: `yourActivityContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...));`

Comment: Eg. for PhysicsHandler also? I knew I could use runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...)) for them to work in UI thread, but I did not try that as I am wondering if there's a better solution. Even if that works, the code would be messy, as I used a lot of handlers as well as PhysicsHandler.

Comment: messy code? refactor!

Comment: I merge all classes into MainActivity. However, in a nested class inside MainActivity, I put MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()), but "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope" occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: I posted it. Now it becomes a pure Java question.

Comment: posted a possible answer, test it and tell me how it will go

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
{
private static Activity thisActivity;

protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
   thisActivity = this;
}

public static class SceneManager1 {

    public static Handler handlerAchievementOwl = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            Log.i("Peakpeak", "Peak inside Handler");

 thisActivity .runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do your magic
                }
            });
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need `context` in a static class (I am not sure if your `MainActivity` has `context`, but I am pretty sure it does somewhere), you could do something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
{
    private static Context context;

    protected void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static class SceneManager1 {

        public static Handler handlerAchievementOwl = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                Log.i("Peakpeak", "Peak inside Handler");

                ((Activity)MainActivity.context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do your magic
                    }
                });
            }

        };
    }

}
```